# request for member in something not in structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Hi I have the below function which is giving me the error as

**error: request for member ‘prev’ in something not a structure or union**

```
void insert(struct node **start){
        struct node *temp=*start,*next_node,obj;
        int pos=0;
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
                printf("The linked list is empty creating the linked list !!!!!!\n");
                next_node=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                if(next_node==NULL)
                {
                        printf("\n Sorry out of Memory !!!!!!! ");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("\n Adding the first element in the list !!!!!!");
                        enterData(&obj);
                        next_node->data1=obj.data1;
                        next_node->data2=obj.data2;
                        next_node->prev=NULL;
                        next_node->next=NULL;
                        *start=next_node;
                        printf("\n The linked list created sucessfully !!!!!!!!! ");
                }
        }
        else{
                printf("Enter the position where you want to Enter the element \n");
                scanf("%d",&pos);
                if(pos==1)
                {
                        printf("\n Adding the element at the begining of the list !!!!! ");
                        next_node=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        enterData(&obj);
                        next_node->data1=obj.data1;
                        next_node->data2=obj.data2;
                        next_node->prev=NULL;
                        next_node->next=*start;
                        *start->prev=next_node; //The error is at this line of code
                        *start=next_node;
                }
        }
}
```

But if instead of using `*start` in the Line of code above mentioned along with the comment if i use `temp` which is also the pointer to the structure. Then code works fine ..? Why is that so ?

Comment: Change `*start` with `(*start)`. The `->` probably has precedence over the `*`.

Comment: A more elaborated comment (since an answer has already been given since the previous comment): The type of `start` is `struct node **`. The type of `temp` is `struct node *`. So your question "why `*start` yields an error while `temp` doesn't" is for a good reason. At this point, you don't even need to know anything about the rules of operator-precedence. Simply try to replace `*start` with `(*start)` and see if it solves the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `*start->prev` with `(*start)->prev` because `->` operator binds tighter than `*` operator in [C precedance table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

When you write: `*start->prev`
You expect it to be: `(*start)->prev`
But actually it is: `*(start->prev)`

---

<sup>p.s. Operator are not ordered from left to right (reading direction of english) as one might expect. For example result of `2 + 3 * 5` is `17` and **not** `25`. This is because `*` will be performed before performing `+`, because `*` operator has more precedance than `+` operator.</sup>